# Chained Exceptions initCause(), is this correct?

Tags: java

I have a method:

```
public void SomeDataMethod() throws BadDataException {
try {

// do something
} catch(IOException e) {
    throw new BadDataException("Bad data",e);
} finally {
  // do something regardless of above
}

}
```

And now for example some code will invoke this method, and I want to see all failures which happened in this method,

**so how can I do it by using initCause()**? **Or maybe is there any other way to do this?** And if I use initCause():

1) will I get all exceptions which were catch or the last one?

2) and What form do I get them / it?**

Comment: How would you get the last `Exception` thrown? Or all of them? When an `Exception` is thrown in your code the program with `goto` the `catch` block and exit the method. You will get the _first_ `Exception` thrown. The cause will be in the form of the `IOException` you are wrapping.

Comment: Your code correctly implements exception chaining. Why do you want to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the cause of an exception, you call... [`getCause()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause%28%29). In this case, this method will return the IOException that you wrapped inside your BadDataException. It can't return more that one exception, since you can only wrap one exception.

Answer (score 1):

When you call an Excepion Constructor with the throwable attached, like you have the `e` as part of the `new BadDataException("Bad data",e);` then the result is effectively the same as:

```
BadDataException bde = new BadDataException("Bad data");
bde.initCause(e);
```

This is to keep compatibility with earlier Java versions which did not have the initCause concept.

Not all exceptions support adding the cause as part of the constructor, and for those exceptions you can `initCause` it.

note that you can only `initCause` an exception once, and initializing it with 'null' cannot later be changed:

```
BadDataException bde = new BadDataException("Bad data", null);
// this will fail.....
bde.initCause(e);
```